# Can one create a video from sequence of meshes that you already have using blender?

Tags: animation, mesh, import

If I have a sequence of .obj (or any other readable format) files created from my own simulation code (say cloth simulation), can I use the rendering capabilities of blender to generate a video?

Is there a way to set the material properties for frame `1` and use the same or rest of the frames while the corresponding meshes are imported afresh from that ones I provide?

Answer (score 3):

If you can get your sequence into a `.MDD` or `.PC2` format, you can try using the [*Mesh Cache*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9R39TVqq-Ss) modifier.

If that doesn't work, you can try [this addon](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?252844-Script-Meshfoot-OBJ-Sequence-Manager-%28revised-for-Blender-2-66%29) which handles `.obj` sequences.

A third option is to write your own python script to toggle the visibility of each mesh so it is visible for only one frame. You can do this with a script that sets the [`object.hide_render`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.hide_render) property accordingly.

You can copy materials to from the active to the selected objects with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>*> Materials*.

Comment: The Meshfoot plugin is no longer available. The closest solution may be here http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?292968-AddOn-Import-OBJ-Sequence-As-Shape-Keys%28on-one-object%29&highlight=object+sequence

Answer (score 0):

I solved this via conversion to PC2 and using the PointCache modifier. BUT, this method only works if you have the same number of vertices and faces throughout your entire simulation. if so, suggest:

1. write a script to convert your obj (vertex data) to a pointcache file. Have a look at the python script in Blender io_export_pc2.py, this will give you the pc2 binary file format.
2. create a basis or reference mesh - build this from the first .obj mesh in your sequence. From what I could figure out, the pc2 file holds vertex information only, and assumes the topology in the basis mesh does not change. hence the need for this step
3. apply the pointcache modifier to the basis mesh, pointing at your .pc2 file
4. adjust the pointcache modifier settings. I used custom, setting the time/frames to align with the an integer multiple of the number of meshes/timesteps. I assigned 50 outputs meshes to stretch over 200 frames, and Blender interpolated the point locations in between
5. assign keyframes - keyframe the first and last time reference in the pointcache modifier

thusly, during animation the vertex locations should move in accordance with the pointcache data.  Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a bit late, but I recently developed a Blender add-on for importing OBJ sequences (it also supports STL and PLY). It's called Stop Motion OBJ. It supports objects with changing topology (different number of vertices on each frame). Here's a [link](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?401143-Add-on-Stop-motion-OBJ-(OBJ-sequence-importer)) to the blenderartists thread where I announced it. Make sure to read through the README on the Github page for some important notes on how to use it.