# Mesh for each keyframe

Tags: animation, mesh, import

Through the usage of a simulation framework, I have for each simulated time step a mesh (.ply format). This results in a collection of meshes. They represent an object deforming over time with each mesh representing a certain point in time. I know how to import these files but how can I easily and automatically animate the deformation given these files?

My question is similar to:  [import series of meshes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27107/import-series-of-meshes) but in my case the number of vertices and faces in each mesh differ. Therefore I do not know if the solution is still valid. 
Another similar question is: [Can one create a video from sequence of meshes that you already have using blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5040/can-one-create-a-video-from-sequence-of-meshes-that-you-already-have-using-blend/27314#27314) which offers the same solution: convert format to PC2 or MDD formats and use Mesh Cache but there it explicitly says that the mesh needs to have the same amount of faces and vertices throughout the entire simulation.

Comment: You might try the Blender add-on [Stop Motion OBJ](https://github.com/neverhood311/Stop-motion-OBJ). It supports sequences of .PLY, .OBJ, and .STL files. It also supports geometry with different vertex counts from frame to frame.